# ANTLR NoViableAltException

Tags: antlr, antlr4

I am running into this again and again. To parse `{1}SB0$1:U` insied this input `S:G$mabit$0$0({1}SB0$1:U),H,0,0` I have these rules here:

```
/*
 *  Type Chain Record
 */

type_chain_record
    :
    '{' number[10] '}' type_dcl_id (',' type_dcl_id)? ':' type_sign
    ;

type_dcl_id
    :
      'DA' EXPRESSION 'd'                 // Array of n elements
    | 'DF'                                      // Function
    | 'DG'                                      // Generic pointer
    | 'DC'                                      // Code pointer
    | 'DX'                                      // External ram pointer
    | 'DD'                                      // Internal ram pointer
    | 'DP'                                      // Page pointer
    | 'DI'                                      // Upper 128 byte pointer
    | 'SL'                                      // long
    | 'SI'                                      // int
    | 'SC'                                      // char
    | 'SS'                                      // short
    | 'SV'                                      // void
    | 'SF'                                      // float
    | 'ST' EXPRESSION                   // Structure of name <name>
    | 'SX'                                      // sbit
    | 'SB' EXPRESSION '$' EXPRESSION    // Bit field of n bits
    ;

type_sign
    :
      'U' // Unsigned
    | 'S' // Signed
    ;


number[int numbase] returns[long val]
    :
    n = EXPRESSION
    {
        $val = Convert.ToInt64($n.text, $numbase);
    }
    ;


// ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// LEXER RULES

fragment LETTER 
    :
      'a'..'z' 
    | 'A'..'Z'
    ;

fragment DIGIT
    :
    '0'..'9'
    ;

fragment NONZERO_DIGIT
    :
    '1'..'9'
    ;


FILE_SCOPE
  :
  'L' (LETTER)+ '.' (LETTER)+
  ;

EXPRESSION
  :
  (LETTER | DIGIT | '_' )+
  ;

WS 
  :
  '\r' | '\n'
  ;
```

I don't understand why but I am getting a `NoViableAltException` saying `line x:y no viable alternative at input 'SB0'`.

Could anyone explain me why this is happening? The parser rule `type_dcl_id` has unique literals in front of every choice. I don't see why the parser would have troubles at this point.

I added all lexer rules.

**Side note:**

The reason why I want that granularity and not simple parse over that input is that I want `type_dcl_id` later to return an object which shall be propagated up to `type_chain_record` and later be used to construct another object `ChainRecord` which will hold an object `DCLType`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SB0` gets tokenized as an `EXPRESSION`, because the lexer will match longest possible sequence and obviously `SB0` is longer than `SB`.

An easy workaround would be to make `LETTER` and `DIGIT` real lexer rules instead of fragments and exchange the `EXPRESSION` lexer rule by the following new parser rule:

```
expression : (LETTER | DIGIT | '_' )+ ;
```

For more information you might find this post helpful: https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/issues/485#issuecomment-37284837

Answer (score 1):

`| 'SB' EXPRESSION '$' EXPRESSION    // Bit field of n bits`

does not match SBO.

Comment: `EXPRESSION` can be `DIGIT`, `LETTER` or `_` so imho this should parse `SB0$1`.

Comment: SB0 must be following by another EXPRESSION as I *answered* above. Your grammar does not allow SB0 in isolation.

Comment: @TheANTLRGuy Then I don't understand. `0` can be an `EXPRESSION`, so why doesn't it recognize `0` as the expression followed by `$ EXPRESSION`?

Comment: SB matches the 'SB' and 0 matches the *first* EXPRESSION. It then *requires* '$' which does not exist in string "SB0", right?